# How to convert GL_TRIANGLES to GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, .obj, gl-triangle-strip

I have data from *.obj file.

I know how draw with `GL_TRIANGLES`. How i can convert data for `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`?

like `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, numberOfFaces);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non trivial problem, and generally not something you want to do anyway, but there are a couple of external libraries out there to take care of this, like this one:

http://users.telenet.be/tfautre/softdev/tristripper/

Comment: thanks, i will look on this solution and write my thoughts here

Comment: so, thanks again, I wrote more simple solution based on that sources

Comment: Hi @SAKrisT, I have a similar problem, can you share the code you wrote?

Comment: @AlexandreOS sorry, I can't share my solution, because it commercial project.